# How to find best FFmpeg libx265 encoding settings for a specific (set of) file(s)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have only recently discovered `FFmpeg` and tried using the `x265` video codec to reduce the video stream size for some videos, and realized that I can achieve tremendous space savings, especially for video recorded via smarthphones. As I'm new to this, I tried doing some research and found that mostly it's about choosing the correct `CRF` and `preset`, so I am thinking it would be sufficient to write a script which iterates through these, creating samples which I could look at and decide what's the best option for a given (set of) video(s).

Is this enough, or should I take some other things into consideration as well? If so, what would the best solution? What is the potential range for a good `CRF` value? (I am thinking 20-30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I'm new to this, I tried doing some research and found that mostly it's about choosing the correct CRF and preset

You are correct:

1. Choose the highest CRF value that provides an acceptable quality.
2. Choose the slowest preset that you have patience for.

Encode some random segments from typical inputs. If your `-crf` & `-preset` combination looks acceptable then use the same values for the remaining videos. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more info.

You didn't mention audio, but consider using [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode (`-c:a copy`), or if you want to re-encode it then Opus (`-c:a libopus`) is hard to beat assuming the format doesn't really matter to you.

Comment: Thank you, I did look at the wiki (the H.264 page as well, which is more elaborate), I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything else that would be worth paying attention to. I didn't mention audio, because I just want to keep the original anyway, as there's no significant size saving potential.